# Every natural number is covered by consecutive numbers that sum to a prime power.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, integers, natural-numbers

**Conjecture**. For every natural number $n \in \Bbb{N}$, there exists a finite set of consecutive numbers $C\subset \Bbb{N}$ containing $n$ such that $\sum\limits_{c\in C} c$ is a prime power.

A list of the first few numbers in $\Bbb{N}$ has several different covers by such consecutive number sets.

One such is:

```
 3   7  5 13  8  19  11  25    29   16     37    41          49    53
___ ___ _ ___ _ ____ __ _____ _____ __ __ _____ _____       _____ _____    __
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
        ___   ___                _____             _____ __       ________ 
        11    17                   31                43              81
59               71           3^5
___    __       _____    _________________ 
 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 .....
 _____    _____    _____
  61       67        73
```

Has this been proved already?

Comment: Apparently, primes are allowed as well. Not sure, whether it has been proven, but this is very likely to be the case. More interesting is to exclude the primes.

Comment: @Peter: The sum can only be a prime if it has at most two terms. (Since $\sum_{k=m}^nk=(n-m+1)(n+m)/2$, which factorizes unless $n-m+1\le2$.) The density of one- and two-term sums that are primes goes to zero, so the brunt of the conjecture has to be borne by the proper prime powers, anyway.

Comment: @Peter a prime power by definition includes the exponent $1$.  Therefore, for sake of simplicity, we include the primes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For any odd prime $p$, there are $p$ consecutive integers centred on $p$ that sum to $p^2$.

$2+3+4=3^2$
$3+4+5+6+7=5^2$
$4+5+6+7+8+9+10=7^2$
etc.

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. Then, using [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) in the form $$p_{n+1}<2p_n$$we know that the above sums for consecutive primes overlap.

Finally, we note that $1+2=3$ to complete the proof.

---

I don't know if this has been shown before, but the proof seems straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

While [nickgard](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/420432/nickgard)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3506433/602049) shows how to solve the problem using sums being squares of increasing primes, this answer shows how to do it using the sums being just odd powers of $3$.

As suggested in [joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506020/every-natural-number-is-covered-by-consecutive-numbers-that-sum-to-a-prime-power#comment7211251_3506020), for any integers $1 \le j \le k$, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=j}^{k}i & = \sum_{i=1}^{k}i - \sum_{i=1}^{j-1}i \\
& = \frac{k(k+1)}{2} - \frac{(j-1)(j)}{2} \\
& = \frac{k^2 + k - j^2 + j}{2} \\
& = \frac{(k-j)(k+j) + k + j}{2} \\
& = \frac{(k+j)(k-j+1)}{2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Consider the ranges $\left[\frac{3^m + 1}{2},\frac{3^{m+1} - 1}{2}\right]$ for $m = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$. The union of these disjoint subsets cover all positive integers. Thus, for any $n \ge 1$, there's a unique $m$ where $n \in \left[\frac{3^m + 1}{2},\frac{3^{m+1} - 1}{2}\right]$. For that $m$, since $\frac{5\left(3^{m}\right)-1}{2} \gt \frac{3^{m+1} - 1}{2}$, you can have $j = \frac{3^m + 1}{2}$ and $k = \frac{5\left(3^{m}\right)-1}{2}$ with $n \in [j,k]$. Using this in \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=j}^{k}i & = \frac{(k+j)(k-j+1)}{2} \\
& = \frac{\left(\frac{5\left(3^{m}\right)-1}{2}+\frac{3^m + 1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{5\left(3^{m}\right)-1}{2}-\frac{3^m + 1}{2}+1\right)}{2} \\
& = \frac{\left(\frac{6\left(3^{m}\right)}{2}\right)\left(\frac{4\left(3^{m}\right)}{2}-\frac{2}{2}+1\right)}{2} \\
& = \frac{\left(3\left(3^{m}\right)\right)\left(2\left(3^{m}\right)\right)}{2} \\
& = \left(3^{m+1}\right)\left(3^{m}\right) \\
& = 3^{2m+1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

The first few examples for $m = 0, 1$ and $2$ are

$$1 + 2 = 3 = 3^{1} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

$$2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 27 = 3^{3} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

$$5 + 6 + \ldots + 21 + 22 = 243 = 3^{5} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$